# Convert column of unix objects to datetime - python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, timedelta

I'm looking to convert a UNIX timestamp object to pandas date time. I'm importing the timestamps from a separate source, which displays a date time of `21-01-22 00:01` for the first timepoint and `21-01-22 00:15` for the second time point. Yet my conversion is 10 hours behind these two. Is this related to the +1000 at the end of each string?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Time' : ['/Date(1642687260000+1000)/','/Date(1642688100000+1000)/'],
   })

df['Time'] = df['Time'].str.split('+').str[0]
df['Time'] = df['Time'].str.split('(').str[1]
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit = 'ms')
```

Out:

```
                 Time
0 2022-01-20 14:01:00
1 2022-01-20 14:15:00
```

Other source:

```
                 Time
0 2022-01-21 00:01:00
1 2022-01-21 00:15:00
```

Comment: [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) with a UTC offset? If you *add* the UTC offset (10 hours here), you get the expected result?

Comment: Yeh ok, so just add 10hrs to every timestamp. 4 separate functions seem like overkill. Suppose it doesn't really matter

Comment: That has potential to go on my list of most weird representations of date and time. Why not provide Unix time + a time zone? It's not even standard to *add* the UTC offset; normally, you specify it so that it has to be *subtracted*! At least they use forward slashes in the string ^^ Seriously, I don't see a way around processing this in multiple steps (remove unnecessary part of the string, split Unix time from offset, parse both etc.).

Comment: Yeh, it took me ages to work out what the hell +10 was for. All good. As long is it works, I'll leave as is. If you want to add an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll delete the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to extract Unix time and UTC offset, then parse Unix time to datetime and add the UTC offset as a timedelta, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Time' : ['/Date(1642687260000+1000)/','/Date(1642688100000+1000)/', None],
   })

df[['unix', 'offset']] = df['Time'].str.extract(r'(\d+)([+-]\d+)')

# datetime from unix first, leaves NaT for invalid values
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['unix'], unit='ms')
# where datetime is not NaT, add the offset:
df.loc[~df['datetime'].isnull(), 'datetime'] += (
                  pd.to_datetime(df['offset'][~df['datetime'].isnull()], format='%z').apply(lambda t: t.utcoffset())
          )

# or without the apply, but by using an underscored method:
# df['datetime'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['unix'], unit='ms') + 
#                   pd.to_datetime(df['offset'], format='%z').dt.tz._offset)

df['datetime']
# 0   2022-01-21 00:01:00
# 1   2022-01-21 00:15:00
# 2                   NaT
# Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Unfortunately, you'll have to use an underscored ("private") method, if you want to avoid the `apply`. This also only works if you have a constant offset, i.e. if it's the same offset throughout the whole series.

Comment: Thanks @MrFuppes. The offset will be constant but one issue could be null values. I might have to adapt with a `try, except` control logic?

Comment: @jonboy good point, I have updated the answer how this can be handled *in principle*. I hope you can apply this to your specific case. Btw. if you could use the "underscored method", no modification should be needed.